# Timing MLlib algorithms when executed in Scala interactive shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using Spark’s Scala (interactive) Shell to experiment with MLlib algorithms, e.g. singular value decomposition (SVD), by applying them to different size datasets. Is there a way to find out how long the execution of an algorithm takes when it is executed in the Shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spark shell job status is available at Web interface, 3030 port of your master node.

Open explorer and input URL `http://MASTER_HOSTNAME:3030`

The 3030 port allow you to track the job’s progress and various metrics about its execution, including task durations and cache statistics.

Other useful ports include:

- 8080, entire Spark Cluster information
- 7077, Spark Master information

Reference: [Data exploration using spark](http://ampcamp.berkeley.edu/3/exercises/data-exploration-using-spark.html).